# Vue.js vuex unknown action type

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm really scratching my head on this one - anybody got any ideas? In my App.vue, I've got these 2 calls:

```
bus.$on('loadTeams', (data) => {
  this.$store.dispatch('updateTeams', data)
})
bus.$on('loadDepartments', (data) => {
  this.$store.dispatch('updateDepartments', data)
})
```

They both get called correctly (I've confirmed that...). Now, in my vuex store.js, I have this:

```
 mutations: {
   ....
   updateDepartments: (state, payload) => {
     state.departments = payload
   },
   updateTeams: (state, payload) => {
     state.teams = payload
   },
   ...
 }
```

updateTeams works fine, but updateDepartments errors with:

```
[vuex] unknown action type: updateDepartments
```

...but I just can't see why. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you committed to actions that you dispatch it at the component?

Comment: dispatch is for actions, not mutations.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to call mutations directly dont `dispatch` but use `commit`. Dispatch is for actions. This video helped me understand the difference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFh7-HfODYY

Comment: But updateTeams and many others are called in *exactly* the same way, and they all work. Only update Departments doesn't! :-(

Answer (score 0):

You do not dispatch a mutation, you commit it, so change the code to

```
bus.$on('loadTeams', (data) => {
  this.$store.commit('updateTeams', data)
})
bus.$on('loadDepartments', (data) => {
  this.$store.commit('updateDepartments', data)
})
```